# Proof that any $n$-dimensional real valued function can be expressed by the product of $n$ one dimensional real valued continuous functions?

Tags: functions

I need to prove that any $n$-dimensional real valued function can be expressed by the product of $n$ one dimensional real valued continuous functions. In other words, that for all continuous $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb N\ni i\leq n$, there exists $f_i:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ continuous such that $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\prod_{i=1}^nf_i(x_i)$.

I have no clue where to start tackling this problem. I have a feeling its true, but I don't know how to prove it. Thanks.

Comment: That sounds rather unlikely.

Comment: How about $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any such function, we have
$$ f(1,2)f(2,1)=f_1(1)f_2(2)f_1(2)f_2(1)=f_1(1)f_2(1)f_1(2)f_2(2)=f(1,1)f(2,2)$$
A counterexample is $f(x,y)=x+y$ because $3\cdot3\ne 2\cdot 4$.